# Commvault Oracle RMAN Restore to new host

Tags: oracle10g

We use Commvault Simpana 8 and I have a situation where I have backups of an Oracle database on tape that were taken from Host A.  Host A suffered a disk failure (lost its raid configuration) and the sys admins are trying to restore it; in the meantime, I'd working to bring the database back up on another host - Host B.

I'm running into problems and am trying to sort out the parameters that need to be passed to the Commvault media agent to get this to work.  Unfortunately, I do not have access to Commvault support and the backup person is unavailable.

Any one have a clue?

The backups are there and the media agent reported a successful write when they ran last night.

This is what fails:

```
run {
allocate channel t1 device type sbt_tape parms='SBT_LIBRARY=/usr/local/galaxy/Base/libobk.so,BLKSIZE=262144, ENV=(CvClientName=dbsrv2,CvInstanceName=Instance001, CVOraSID=BBPROD)';
restore spfile to pfile '/tmp/bbdb.ora' from autobackup;
} 

allocated channel: t1
channel t1: sid=34 devtype=SBT_TAPE
channel t1: CommVault Systems for Oracle: Version 7.0.0(Build76)

Starting restore at 09-MAY-10

channel t1: looking for autobackup on day: 20100509
channel t1: autobackup found: c-3941155360-20100509-01
released channel: t1
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: failure of restore command at 05/09/2010 18:01:35
ORA-19870: error reading backup piece c-3941155360-20100509-01
ORA-19507: failed to retrieve sequential file, handle="c-3941155360-20100509-01", parms=""
ORA-27029: skgfrtrv: sbtrestore returned error
ORA-19511: Error received from media manager layer, error text:
   sbtrestore: Job[0] thread[26316]: InitializeCLRestore() failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Media Manager layer is actually from the ORASBT link between CommVault and RMAN - so I'd recommend you check the CommVault job logs or the commcell console's event viewer to see what happened when it went to open the archive file/disk/tape for RMAN's request.   Without that detail, you're not going to be able to get any further.

Comment: Thanks.  I opened a call with support (we get ours through Dell), but they can't tell me the proper rman parameters to get this to work.  Since we do not initiate backups through CommVault, but through rman, I'm out of luck with support.  Interesting thing is that if the original host is running, the restore to another server works - next I have to test if the parameters make a difference in that case.  Unfortunately, I can't shutdown the original host to test further.

Answer (score 0):

Can be a lot of things, a communication problem normally or media can´t be mounted. Verify SBTORA.log file on client. CVD.log on Media Agent and JobManager.log on Commserve.